# Do shortcode in template file

Tags: shortcode, archive-template

I have a fairly complicated shortcode that works well when put inside the wysiwyg editor. Now I try to include this in a template PHP file using `do_shortcode` but it doesn't work.

My used but not working PHP source code is:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[gfchartsreports include="28" type="bar" chart_js_options="title: {display: true, text: 'Titletext', fontSize:12,fontFamily:'Arial',fontColor:"#000",fontStyle:"bold",padding:20}" custom_search_criteria='{"status":"active","field_filters":{"0":{"key":"created_by","value":"current"}}}']'); ?>
```

I'm not a PHP pro and so I guess the error will be a beginner's mistake. Could anyone help me out with his coding wisdom?

Thank's a lot for your help!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to escape the quotes:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[gfchartsreports include="28" type="bar" chart_js_options="title: {display: true, text: \'Titletext\', fontSize:12,fontFamily:\'Arial\',fontColor:"#000",fontStyle:"bold",padding:20}" custom_search_criteria=\'{"status":"active","field_filters":{"0":{"key":"created_by","value":"current"}}}\']'); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you Abdul! This was exactly what I was looking for. Helpful and educational. And best of all: it works ;-)